# how to pass binary data in websocket in order to reduce traffic?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, binary

how to covert string to binary data in order to reduce network traffic?

```
* use websocket
* it should be in client environment like chrome.
```

for example

turn **hello world** to binary data, then send it to server with websocket.

server can take received data as binary.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome supports [WebSocket compression](https://www.igvita.com/2013/11/27/configuring-and-optimizing-websocket-compression/). This will transparently reduce wire level volume for both WebSocket text and binary messages.